# Get podio spacemembers active members only

Tags: php, podio

We have a workspace on Podio with 1400 spacemembers, and we want to cleanup the space so we only have active members. Its also required by GDPR that we cannot have data on inactive users more than a year. 
So I've made a function that gets all the spacemembers with the API,
`$userobject = PodioSpaceMember::get_by_role(MY_SPACE_ID, 'light' );`

and I am able to get the `last_seen_on` property on each user. But some of the userobjects only return a boolean value instead of a datetime object. Does this mean that the user has never loggedin?

```
$last_seen_date = $userobject->profile->last_seen_on;
$last_seen = date_format($last_seen_date, 'Y-M-D');
echo 'Last seen: '.$last_seen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely - yes.

To be absolutely sure, please submit support ticket at https://help.podio.com, include some of user's IDs and also add link to this question so support team will know that you've already raised this question on StackOverflow.